# How can I filter multiple variables with different restrictions on each variable at the same time in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, data.table

I am trying to filter out the top 1% of of each numeric variable in a dataframe. I tried a loop function, but could not find a syntax that worked. And I could not get filter(across()) to work either, but I am not familiar that syntax either.

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(var_1=seq(1,10,1),
           var_2=-seq(1,100,10),
           var_3=seq(-5,4,1),
           var_4=seq(5500,55000,10000),
           var_5=rep(c("text 1","text 2", "text 3","text 4","text 5"),2))

top_one_percent<-sapply(select_if(df, is.numeric),quantile,.99)

  var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4  var_5
1      1    -1    -5  5500 text 1
2      2   -11    -4 15500 text 2
3      3   -21    -3 25500 text 3
4      4   -31    -2 35500 text 4
5      5   -41    -1 45500 text 5
6      6   -51     0  5500 text 1
7      7   -61     1 15500 text 2
8      8   -71     2 25500 text 3
9      9   -81     3 35500 text 4
10    10   -91     4 45500 text 5

var_1.99% var_2.99% var_3.99% var_4.99% 
     9.91     -1.90      3.91  45500.00
```

Is there a way to do this using dplyr, data.table, a loop, or the base functions?
The manual answer I would expect is:

```
df%>%
  filter(var_1<9.91)%>%
  filter(var_2<(-1.9))%>%
  filter(var_3<3.91)%>%
  filter(var_4<45500)
```

Which gives:

```
  var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4  var_5
1     2   -11    -4 15500 text 2
2     3   -21    -3 25500 text 3
3     4   -31    -2 35500 text 4
4     6   -51     0  5500 text 1
5     7   -61     1 15500 text 2
6     8   -71     2 25500 text 3
7     9   -81     3 35500 text 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(if_all(where(is.numeric), ~ . < quantile(., 0.99)))
#   var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4  var_5
# 1     2   -11    -4 15500 text 2
# 2     3   -21    -3 25500 text 3
# 3     4   -31    -2 35500 text 4
# 4     6   -51     0  5500 text 1
# 5     7   -61     1 15500 text 2
# 6     8   -71     2 25500 text 3
# 7     9   -81     3 35500 text 4
```